# Unable to index UIMA feature type into Solr field

Tags: solr, nlp, opennlp, uima

I am trying to integrate UIMA with Solr.I was able to do the same.But some of the UIMA fields are not getting indexed into solr whereas other fields like pos,ChukType are getting indexed. 
I am using openNLP-UIMA together for text analysis. 
When I tried to index the UIMA field for location extraction,the field is not present in solr index.

**LocationNameFinder.xml** :descriptor file for extracting locations

```
<analysisEngineDescription xmlns="http://uima.apache.org/resourceSpecifier">
        <frameworkImplementation>org.apache.uima.java</frameworkImplementation>
        <primitive>true</primitive>
        <annotatorImplementationName>opennlp.uima.namefind.NameFinder</annotatorImplementationName>
        <analysisEngineMetaData>
                <name>Location Name Finder</name>
                <description></description>
                <version>${pom.version}</version>
                <vendor>Apache Software Foundation</vendor>
                <configurationParameters>

                        <configurationParameter>
                                <name>opennlp.uima.SentenceType</name>
                                <type>String</type>
                                <multiValued>false</multiValued>
                                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                        </configurationParameter>

                        <configurationParameter>
                                <name>opennlp.uima.TokenType</name>
                                <type>String</type>
                                <multiValued>false</multiValued>
                                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                        </configurationParameter>

                        <configurationParameter>
                                <name>opennlp.uima.NameType</name>
                                <type>String</type>
                                <multiValued>false</multiValued>
                                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                        </configurationParameter>
                </configurationParameters>

                <configurationParameterSettings>

                        <nameValuePair>
                                <name>opennlp.uima.SentenceType</name>
                                <value>
                                        <string>uima.tcas.DocumentAnnotation</string>
                                </value>
                        </nameValuePair>

                        <nameValuePair>
                                <name>opennlp.uima.TokenType</name>
                                <value>
                                        <string>opennlp.uima.Token</string>
                                </value>
                        </nameValuePair>

                        <nameValuePair>
                                <name>opennlp.uima.NameType</name>
                                <value>
                                        <string>opennlp.uima.Location</string>
                                </value>
                        </nameValuePair>
                </configurationParameterSettings>

                <typeSystemDescription>
                        <imports>
                                <import location="TypeSystem.xml" />
                        </imports>
                </typeSystemDescription>

                <capabilities>
                        <capability>
                                <inputs />
                                <outputs />
                                <languagesSupported>
                                        <language>en</language>
                                </languagesSupported>
                        </capability>
                </capabilities>
        </analysisEngineMetaData>

        <externalResourceDependencies>
                <externalResourceDependency>
                        <key>opennlp.uima.ModelName</key>
                        <interfaceName>opennlp.uima.namefind.TokenNameFinderModelResource</interfaceName>
                </externalResourceDependency>
        </externalResourceDependencies>

        <resourceManagerConfiguration />
</analysisEngineDescription>
```

The Type description for location:

**TypeSystem.xml:**

```
                     <typeDescription>
                        <name>opennlp.uima.Location</name>
                        <supertypeName>uima.tcas.Annotation</supertypeName>
                        <features>
                                <featureDescription>
                                        <name>location</name>
                                        <description></description>
                                        <rangeTypeName>uima.cas.String</rangeTypeName>
                                </featureDescription>
                        </features>
                </typeDescription>
```

In Solr I have provided mapping for location in the UpdateRequestHandler.

Thanks and Regards